# Spring AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests - does not rollback data after test a method

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, aop, spring-aop

> After running a unit test, data is not getting deleted from the
>   database.

I have a problem with either AOP configuration or spring.
I have written a unit test that extends class AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests.
For AOP configuration I have made a point-cut on the methods that are going to be tested , I have given this advice to the point-cut:

```
<tx:advice id="newTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

please tell me why data is not getting deleted, any help will be appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you writing your data access code? Are you using JDBC, Hibernate, or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

- As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789788/what-exactly-propagation-requires-new-means-using-spring-transaction-managemen), a transaction with `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation attribute is not related to any other wider-scoped transaction.
- `AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`, as an `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests`, does not *delete* stuff, but actually rolls back a test-wide transaction.

So in your case, it is most likely that your transactionManager is committing new transactions as you test stuff, so when your outer tx is rollbacked (by 
`AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests`), it is too late: data has already been committed.

To do what you want, just use the default `REQUIRED` propagation. I'd even recommend not using `REQUIRES_NEW` in general, unless you have a specific use case with exception handling issues.